# Thrombosis risk before launch

Tags: spacex, crewed-spaceflight, health

I am currently following the live broadcast of today's SpaceX launch. For a few hours already, astronauts are sitting inside the vessel, barely able to move. I wonder what precautions are taken to minimize the risk of a thrombosis. Of course health status of astronauts is closely monitored before and throughout a mission. But even a healthy individual does have a risk for thrombosis when sitting still for a longer duration. Do astronauts take blood thinners or take any other precautions?

Comment: `+1` is adrenalin a blood thinner? :-)

Comment: FWIW, can't recall any such precautions during the Shuttle days. I'm guessin' that, for the first manned Crew Dragon mission, the crews' pressure suits fit pretty good and were comfy. Not necessarily true for Shuttle crews, since said suits were "off the shelf."

Comment: @uhoh....   Adrenalin (Epinephrin) both shortens clotting time and increases circulating platelets. Both effects would promote clotting. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1358840/?page=11 https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF00572454 https://www.ahajournals.org/doi/10.1161/01.HYP.25.5.1096

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Muscle contraction in the legs can keep venous blood moving due to valves in the veins. A timed reminder to "wiggle your toes" is all that's needed to prevent thrombosis risk.